# How to pass a token within the message body in a GET method (Restangular)?

Tags: angularjs, rest, get, token, restangular

I am learning and starting now working with Restangular and AngularJS. Therefore the question may seem simple:

I need to send a token, within the GET message and do not appear in the URL.

Ex: `http://www.example.com/patients`

I need to pass

```
{"token": 1}
```

But **I do not want** to appear like this:
`http://example.com/patients?token=1` or something like that.

Works testing with CURL, with the following command:

```
curl -i -X GET -d '{"token": 1}' http://example.com/patients; echo
```

My source code:

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://example.com');

Restangular.all('patients').getList().then(function(records)
     {
       ....
     }
```

Does anyone know what needs to be done?

Comment: Did you think about adding a cookie ? That's what we do here : We have a service who provides tokens that needs to be send to services in order to authenticate the user. Tokens are received and sent has cookies

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your RestangularProvider to respond on POST, for example:

```
Restangular.all('patients').getList().post("patients", $scope.patients).then(function(records)
 {
   ....
 }
```

Then the curl testing should be:

```
curl -i -X POST -d '{"token": 1}' http://example.com/patients; echo
```

Comment: Something like this?
'
    Restangular.all('patients').getList().post("patients", $scope.patients).then(function(records)
    {
        $scope.patients = records;
        console.log("All ok Patients");

    }, function(response)
    {
        console.log("Error Patients ", response.status);
    });
'

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Look the error
`OPTIONS http://example.compatients 400 (Bad Request)
  (anonymous function) 
  s 
  Td.$get.f 
  De.l.promise.then.J 
  De.l.promise.then.J 
  (anonymous function) 
  Yd.$get.h.$eval 
  Yd.$get.h.$digest 
  Yd.$get.h.$apply 
  m 
  w 
  B.onreadystatechange 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/patients. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

Comment: It is. I replaced our domain to 'http://exemplo.com'.... to not show ... but the problem is the XMLHttpRequest (I think)... but I have no idea that "how to make it work"... Tks MarcosS

Comment: With XMLHttpRequest you can't make requests to a different domain than your page is on (which is what that message means). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource. Please be sure your client and your server are on the *very* same domain (included port, for example...).